# hibernate current date criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

In my database, `date` is stored in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format. And I need details of current date's information. I am using hibernate criteria

I have tried with this code

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();

try {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("createdDate", dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date))));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it is not working. Kindly suggest some solution

Comment: Kindly show the error you get.

Comment: "In my db date is in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format"? maybe not, are you sure the type of the column is String.

Comment: there is no error..I t is not fetching proper colums. no rows found..

Comment: NO...it is in date format

Comment: could you show the table definition?